# Including additional authors to reduce time

Tags: authorship, collaboration

I tried to find the same question and failed, so here it goes.

Imagine the following scenario: you have invested time (say 8 months) ona  research project. You would probably get a publication in 4 more months of full time work. However, if you include two experts (who provide code) you could reduce the additional time to roughly one month. In both cases you would remain a first name author.

The trade-off is between the number of authors of the paper and the time you invest.

Would there be a rule of thumb to help me with this decision? Is there a clear answer, or is it completely subjective?

Comment: It depends on the discipline. In some it is normal to have multiple authors. In some you would be considered weird if you have too many single authored papers. In others you would be considered weird if you have too many papers with co-authors.The order matters differently from discipline to discipline etc. etc. etc. It is not subjective, but you need to know the rules in your sub-sub-sub-discipline.

Comment: I was afraid that there would be some degrees of freedom in that problem. I will try to find out the unwritten rules of my niche, but I cannot really think of a methodology to do that.

Comment: first, just talk to advisors or colleagues with experience. Second, look at the recent issues of the relevant journals in your field.

Comment: Maybe adding authors will reduce the amount of time *you* spend, but another consideration is that the overall time to completion may be longer.  Do you know about [Brooks's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%E2%80%99_law)?

Comment: @NateEldredge is absolutely correct. Adding more people to a late project only makes it later. You all have to come up to speed on each others stuff, the documentation gets harder, writing it all up to everyone's satisfaction takes longer. They need to provide more than 'code' - you will need their expertise as well. The real question, admittedly in retrospect now,  is why didn't you include them from the beginning?

Comment: What will you learn by doing the cold yourself?

Comment: @Ian - I love this, take the long view that you may end up being much more efficient in the long run by doing this now.  Nice comment.

Answer (score 1):

As some comments above indicate, there is an important rule of thumb from the field of software engineering, which is [Brooks' Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%E2%80%99_law).

According to Frederick Brooks, in his book *The Mythical Man-Month*, adding more workers to a project which is already behind schedule, is likely to make it even farther behind schedule as new members are brought on board.

Take the time to consider whether you can beat this effect before attempting to grow your group.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I admire Brooks and his work, that cannot be a hard and fast rule.   There are definitely situations where one woefully underestimates time to finish a project *by oneself*.  In the specific case you mention, how long would it really take you to learn the proper code? (And debugging, and annoying modern syntax not in the text you chose, and ...) How expert are the experts - and especially, how well do you know them, have you worked together before, etc.?  If a lot of the tradeoffs in bringing new people on board are sunk costs you've already invested, this can be a great idea.  I can confirm multiple projects where this has worked for me personally - naturally, your mileage may vary.

This answer doesn't directly address the "first-name author" or collaboration business, because in my discipline we tend to pay less attention to that than in others, and I am not in a particularly publish-or-perish position.  But I do believe in the following phrase:

> If you don't care who gets the credit, you can get a lot of work done.

If you are in a situation to work full time on your research anyway, and even if it takes two or three months instead of the four-becoming-six months you estimated, that sounds like a net gain of another small paper or something (again, depending on the field), so you should at the very least seriously consider this option **IF** you have already sunk many of the costs of Brooks' Law.